# Cramer Condition

Tags: probability, statistics, distribution-tails, large-deviation-theory

I was reading the book

> Technical Incerto -
> Statistical Consequences of Fat Tails

by Nassim Nicholas Taleb, in this book the autor writes the following (page 28):

> *"Membership in the subexponential class does not satisfy the so-called Cramer condition, allowing insurability, as we illustrated
> in Figure 3.1, recall out thought experiment in the beginning of the
> chapter. **More technically, the Cramer condition means that the
> expectation of the exponential of the random variable exists.**"*

On a foot note the autor leaves a very simple definition of the Cramer Condition, this condition is referenced along the book:

Let $X$ be a random variable. The Cramer condition: for all $r > 0$, $\mathbb{E}(e^{rX}) < + \infty$,
where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation operator.

I am looking for a more formal definition of the Cramer Condition this author talks about, because I found this definition with some lack of formality, or maybe I am wrong and is more simple than I think it is and this will do. I am aware of subexponential distributions but I can't find anything related to this Cramer condition I thinks it as to do with large deviations theory. Am I in the right way? Will this definition suffice if I talk in a mathematically formal point?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)

Comment: It's not so clear what the context of this is. Usually subexponential random variable is any random variable with a finite moment generating function in a neighborhood of the origin. The given "Cramer condition" guarantees this condition, and the first sentence in your quote is not clear to me.